# Open the Bluetooth Settings Menu in IOS

Tags: ios9, ios-bluetooth

I need to open the bluetooth settings menu in `IOS9.0`. The next opens the Settings Menu OK!,

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

but I need to open the Bluetooth Settings Menu Tried with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth")!)
```

It does not work

Anyone can help me?

Comment: now I know how to do it. It is necessary to include  Info - URL Types - URL schemes - prefs

Answer (score 7):

Luis actually found the answer, but I read past it at first, because I saw no answers.

**Answer:**
Go to your Xcode project, under Info -> URL Types section -> "prefs" in URL Scheme

In iOS 9: `let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Bluetooth")!`

iOS 8: `let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth")!`

Comment: this does helps me

Comment: its prefs:root=Bluetooth for IOS 8.4 at least

Answer (score -1):

You can't open bluetooth settings in iOS 10.

Here is my suggestion to open settings (swift 3)

```
let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```